# How to add an image from camera in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I created a placeholder for an image in my app, on clicking which I want to be able to open camera, and show the image clicked in the placeholder. I used the image_picker package for this. I wrapped my placeholder container with GestureDetector, however nothing happens on tapping on the container. How do i resolve this ?

In my main file containing Stateless widget, i added my Stateful widget addImage()

```
Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[

                  addImage(),  // my stateful widget 
                TextField(

                  )
                ),              
                Row(
                 //other implementation here 
                  ],
                )

              ]
            )
```

My addImage stateful widget looks like this

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';


class addImage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _addImageState createState() => _addImageState();
}

class _addImageState extends State<addImage> {

  File _image;

  Future getImagefromCamera() async{

    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: getImagefromCamera,
      child: _image == null ? Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red[50],border: Border.all(color: Colors.red[200], width: 1.0),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height:30.0),
              Icon(Icons.camera_alt, color: Colors.red),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text('Take Image of the Item', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0)
            ],
          )) : Image.file(_image),
    );
  }

}
```

I even added the dependency in pubspec.yaml , however still doesnt work

```
 image_picker: ^0.4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see the captured image from camera using below code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: addImage()
      )
    );
  }
}

class addImage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _addImageState createState() => _addImageState();
}

class _addImageState extends State<addImage> {

  File _image;

  Future getImagefromCamera() async{

    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: getImagefromCamera,
          child: _image == null ? Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red[50],border: Border.all(color: Colors.red[200], width: 1.0),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height:30.0),
                  Icon(Icons.camera_alt, color: Colors.red),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Text('Take Image of the Item', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0)
                ],
              )) : Image.file(_image),
        )

    );

  }

}
```

Tested on Android emulator.

[image]

Comment: How do I make the image replace the container after i click ? It goes beyond constraints

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
 image_picker: ^0.5.2
```

after try this code..

```
Future<File> imageFile;

pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
setState(() {
  imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
});
}

 Widget showImage() {
 return FutureBuilder<File>(
  future: imageFile,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
        snapshot.data != null) {
      return Image.file(
        snapshot.data,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      );
    } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
      return const Text(
        'Error Picking Image',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'No Image Selected',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  },
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        showImage(),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Select Image from Gallery"),
          onPressed: () {
            pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource.camera);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }
```

Comment: This is still not working...it's calling the pickImageFromGallery() function without even clicking on the container and displaying 'Error Picking Image' in ios simulator. And on android emulator, camera opens as soon as i navigate to the screen and then shows error

Comment: I edited my code like this, not getting desired results
```